# XMLHttp "open" error with new Cordova Version

Tags: cordova, sharepoint, xmlhttprequest, visual-studio-cordova, cordova-4

I'm trying to connect to a Sharepoint 2013 Server to get some lists etc.
I have this HTML-Code where i get my Username/Password/Sharepoint-URL:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *" />
    <title>SP Manager</title>

    <!-- Some Stylesheets -->

    <!-- Cordova-Scripts -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
    <!-- Onsen-UI Scripts -->
    <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/onsenui/js/onsenui.js"></script>
    <!-- Zing Chart -->
    <script src="lib/zingchart_trial/zingchart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/ChartJS/control.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/ChartJS/chart.js"></script>
    <!-- Standard Scripts -->
    <script src="lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/Page JS/index.js"></script>
    <script src="../scripts/SharepointJS/sharepoint.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/TimeJS/scripte.js"></script>

    <script>
        ons.bootstrap();    //Call für OnsenUI-Init
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ons-navigator id="navigator" title="Navigator" var="loginNavigator">
        <ons-page var="pagecontent" >
            <div style="width:100%;" id="logoLogin">
                <img src="Images/logo.png" style="height: 100%;"/>
            </div>
            <div class="login-form">
                <input id="sharepoint" type="text" class="text-input--underbar" placeholder="Sharepoint" style="" onclick="changeSharepointURL(true)" readonly="readonly">
                <input id="username" type="text" class="text-input--underbar" placeholder="Benutzername" value="agile\shau" style="" onclick="clearInput('#username')">
                <input id="password" type="password" class="text-input--underbar" placeholder="Passwort" value="Start@123" style="" onclick="clearInput('#password')">
                <br>
                <ons-button id="LoginButton" onclick="sharepointLogin()" class="login-button">Einloggen</ons-button>
                <br /><br />
                <ons-button class="forgot-password" onclick="SP.loginOffline()">Offline Anmelden</ons-button>

                <ons-button onclick="resetURL()">Reset URL</ons-button>
            </div>
            <div id="errorMessageLogin" style="color:red; text-align:center;">
            </div>
        </ons-page>
    </ons-navigator>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the script im using to connect to my Sharepoint:

```
        var urlSP = window.localStorage.getItem('sharepoint') + "something else";
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
            if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {
                that.usernameID = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText).d.Id; //Get and save the Username-ID from Sharepoint
                window.localStorage.setItem("lastUser", that.usernameID); //Save this ID ín local Storage
                window.localStorage.setItem("username", username); //Save the username in local Storage

                that.password = password;
                callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
            } else {
                $("#errorMessageLogin").html("Wrong Username/Password/URL.");
            }
        }
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET", urlSP, false);
    that.credentials = "Basic " + window.btoa(username + ":" + password); //Save credentials
    window.localStorage.setItem("credentials", that.credentials); //Save in local storage too
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", that.credentials);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
    xmlHttp.send(null);
```

This code works fine with an older Version of Cordova (my mates are using Version 3 I think).

Now if I try to launch the app with the built-in Android emulator from VS2015 and Version 4 of Cordova im getting this error:

```
Refused to connect to 'my SP adress' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
sharepoint.js (111,17)

Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Refused to connect to 'my SP adress' because it violates the document's Content Security Policy.
sharepoint.js (111,17)
```

I have read that I need the whitelist Plugin from cordova in order to execute the request. I have added it to the Project (with VS) along with this code in the config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<widget xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:vs="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/htmlapps" id="io.cordova.myappd6b043" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" defaultlocale="de-DE">
  <name>SP Manager</name>
  <description>A blank project that uses Apache Cordova to help you build an app that targets multiple mobile platforms: Android, iOS, Windows, and Windows Phone.</description>
  <author href="http://cordova.io" email="dev@cordova.apache.org">Apache Cordova Team </author>
  <content src="index.html" />
  <access origin="*" />

  <!-- #################ADDED THIS LINE############## -->
  <allow-intent href="https://my SP adress/*" />

  <vs:features />
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
  <preference name="windows-target-version" value="8.1" />
  <!-- Support for Cordova 5.0.0 plugin system -->
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
  <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
  <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
  <platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
  </platform>
  <!-- some icon sources -->
  <vs:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1.2.0" />
</widget>
```

but it still doesn't work.

EDIT: My mate updated his cordova in VS2015 and its working without any problems... I'm confused...
Even a reinstall didn't work...

Comment: Have you tried to completely comment your Content-Security-Policy meta-tag? Just to see if it is the source of your problem.

Comment: Yes, but then im getting the same error as with the other meta tag from Filipe Pinto (Access-Control-Allow-Origin).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could make your Content Security Police more permissive. I use this one:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' * gap://ready; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; media-src *"/>
```

Comment: I tried it and now im getting some other errors.
`XMLHttpRequest cannot load MY SP ADRESS. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4400' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.
sharepoint.js (117,17)`